# How do I add a shortcut to the Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, shortcuts

I know how to create a [.desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) file in `~/.local/share/applications/` and add it to the Launcher (just drag it from Files onto the Launcher), but the problems are:

1. I can't find the shortcut via Dash. Typing its name reveals nothing.
2. The shortcut is gone from the Launcher after a reboot.

The instructions at [Adding a .desktop file to the Unity Launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Adding_a_.desktop_file_to_the_Unity_Launcher) just don't work. My files validate, and I've run `desktop-file-install`, but they still don't show up in the Dash search.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and here's the contents of the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=FB2K
Terminal=false
Name=Foobar2000
Exec=wine /c/Utils/foobar2000/foobar2000.exe
Type=Application
Icon=/c/Utils/foobar2000/foobar2000.png
Categories=Music;AudioVideo;
Hidden=true
```

Comment: Seems like a bug. Items added to launcher should stay there - that's the proper behavior. I strongly suggest you report this as bug on Launchpad

Comment: Hi Dan, could you post the content of the launcher? The validator mostly checks on syntax, but there can be other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there's no

```
Hidden=true
```

line in the .desktop file.

---

No idea how that line got in there - possibly created by `alacarte`?

Thanks to Jacob Vlijm for suggesting that I post the contents of the file.

Comment: Hi Dan, great that you found it. It is better not to include part of the answer in the question, you already mention it in the answer. Alacarte indeed does unwanted stuff to files. Not sure if this is one :)